$ \lambda^{*}(n) $ minimal polynomials
I already asked a closely related question on MSE.
Considering the modular lambda function, the values of $ \lambda^{*}(n) $ for some integers are given on here.
Is there a way to calculate the coefficients of the minimal polynomials of each $ \lambda^{*}(n) $ ?
Here you have the minimal polynomials for the first $10$ positive integers, found with Mathematica
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  P_n(x) \\ \hline
 1 & 2x^2-1        \\ \hline
 2 & x^2+2x-1    \\ \hline
 3 & 16x^4-16x^2+1 \\ \hline
 4 & x^2-6x+1  \\ \hline
5 & 16x^{8} - 32x^{6} + 88x^4 - 72 x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
6 & x^{4} + 12x^{3} +2x^2 - 12x +1 \\ \hline
7 & 256x^4 - 256x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
8 & x^{4} - 20x^{3} - 26x^2 - 20x +1 \\ \hline
9 & 16x^{8} - 32x^{6} + 792x^4 - 776x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
10 & x^{4} + 36x^{3} + 2x^2 - 36 x + 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

There is way to compute the modular equation of degree $p$ for the modular function $\lambda$ but its mostly theoretical. Calculating actual coefficients is a computational problem and further if $P(x, y) =0$ is the modular equation we need to substitute $x=\lambda, y=1-\lambda$ to get the desired polynomial equation for $\lambda$ as $P(\lambda, 1-\lambda)=0$.

@ParamanandSingh thank you for the answer and sorry for the late reply. Could you please give me any reference?

You should check Borwein's Pi and the AGM from page 119 onwards.
